# Facebook Page/App Testing Environment

Tags: facebook

I am trying to set up a test environment to test Facebook pages & apps... since I am new to Facebook development I am hoping to get advice from someone who's had more experience than I with building Facebook apps...

I was planning on setting up a test Facebook page that is private (only visible to admins). Then create & add sandbox apps to the private page.

I need the page & apps to NOT be visible to the public in this test environment at all. However, I need to be able to add more developers, admins, & testers to access the testing environment. I think I should be able to accomplish this by adding admins to the Facebook page & adding developers/testers to the Facebook apps. Unfortunately, it appears Facebook does not have a "full" sandbox feature for pages & apps. So, is this the best way to set up an environment for testing pages & apps within the Facebook environment?

Comment: Any luck with this? Were you able to add your sandbox app to your private page?

Answer (score 2):

@Brigette by default it is private. The app you create is only assessable to you or to people you want to assign in your development team. Your friends will not be able to see it nor will it be searchable. It will not be visible until you actually publish it. Have a read on Facebook Developer - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

The docs are quite good and what you cant find have a snoop in the forums as most of the questions you may have are already answered. Hope that helps. :)